# Is it allowed to have value for list item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <ul id="my-list">
     <li value="1001">item1 </li>
     <li value="1002">item2 </li>
     <li value="1003">item3 </li>
     <li value="1004">item4 <li/>
 </ul>
```

Is it allowed to have value for list item? If I can, how to access the value using javascript or jquery?

Comment: Sure, you can have a value. Just use access it using jQuery's `.val()` or JS `.value`.

Comment: Something strange seems to be going on with votes to answers on this question. I've seen 5 downvotes, 5 upvotes and then a further 2 downvotes to a single question in less than 30 seconds.

Comment: For LI tags, "the value attribute can be used when the parent element in only an ol element". http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/li#HTML_Attributes

Comment: A syntax check of your markup will tell you if something is valid or not. And it's also a good practice to check with the specification docs.

Comment: Why are people down-voting the use of the data attributes?

Comment: @thomthom i don't understand it either...

Comment: Nevermind all these lawyers and their technical mumbo-jumbo. You asked if it was **allowed** and the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks for answering ..   this will work ..
var lisX = document.getElementById("my-list").getElementsByTagName("li");
    var array=lisX[1].value;

Comment: Will it work? Yes. Will it validate, most likely not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [W3C specification for `LI` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li) it is allowed to use `value` attribute for `LI` in some cases, but not this one. If you're using HTML5 use [`data-*` attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes):

```
<ul id="my-list>
   <li data-my-value="...">...</li>
   <li data-my-value="123">...</li>
   <li data-my-value="...">...</li>
</ul>
```

To get a reference to a particular element using jQuery use following selector:

```
$("ul#my-list li[data-my-value='123']")...
```

Or, if you already got reference to all `LI` elements use [`jQuery.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var $items = $listItems.filter(function() {
    retrun $(this).data("my-value") === "123";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any sort of *custom* data attributes to your node (of course that HTML won't validate and it won't be a valid XHTML document). You can then access them using jQuery [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function (for example).

That said it's a **terrible practice** and you should use a standard `data-` attribute, accessible for example with [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function (more details and examples in the provided link):

```
var theValue = $("#yourItemId").data("value");
```

For an attribute like:

```
<li id="yourItemId" data-value="1001">item1</li>
```

Comment: How is that a *"Terrible practice"*? As an example, jQuery uses expando properties all over in IE.

Comment: @David "_...all over **IE**._" is a good reason to avoid them. It's non standard. Of course you can add any sort of attributes to any element and you may write non standard HTML (or even malformed, browsers will _understand_ it) but IMO _possible_ doesn't mean _good_ (unless absolutely necessary and without any other choice).

Comment: And *good* doesn’t mean *allowed*. I’d still call that a highly subjective point of view, even if the term "allowed" is vague and apparently encourages personal interpretations.

Comment: @David well of course anything that can be done is just a point of view but I would skip to start each sentence with "IMO"...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to produce *valid* HTML5, you should stick to the `data` attributes for custom properties:

```
<li data-value="1001">
```

However, any element can have a custom attribute. In fact this has been standard in IE since version 5 (sometimes called *expando properties*).

Answer (score 0):

For this purposes I would recommended use jquery [Data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)

```
<ul id="my-list">
 <li data-value="1001">item1 </li>
 <li data-value="1002">item2 </li>
 <li data-value="1003">item3 </li>
 <li data-value="1004">item4 <li/>
</ul>
```

Get second li value

```
$("#my-list").children().eq(2).data("value");
```